# Object serialization trouble (c#)

Tags: c#, serialization

Dear Stack Overflow community,
I thought I'd never have to ask this question, but apparently something is going wrong with serialization or my usage of it.

I have a class which I need to serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class Device : ISerializable, IDisposable
{
   public delegate void ListChangedEventHandler(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e);
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string IPAddress { get; set; }

   [Browsable(false)]
   public ThreadSafeBindingList<Item> Items { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public MibEntity AssociatedMibEntity { get; set; }

    //methods etc.
}
```

**A little explanation:**

ThreadSafeBindingList is inherited from System.ComponentModel.BindingList
MibEntity is a class of SharpSNMP library (http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/)

**Problem:**
When I try to deserialize the object, MibEntity is always null. Other properties are fine.
MibEntity class is in external dll, which I reference in the project where Device class resides.

**This is its content:**

```
[Serializable]
public class MibEntity 
{
    public MibEntity()
    {
        Children = new List<MibEntity>(); 
    } 

    [Browsable(false)]
    public List<MibEntity> Children { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("General")]
    public string OID { get; set; }

    private string _name;
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("General")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Value { get; set; }


    [Browsable(true)]
    public AccessType AccessType { get; set; } //this is enum from SharpSNMP library

    [Browsable(true)]
    public Status Status { get; set; } //this is enum from same assembly as this class

    [Browsable(true)]
    public string Syntax { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public bool IsTableEntry { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public IDefinition IDefinition { get; set; } //this is interface from SharpSNMP library
}
```

I use BinaryFormatter for serialization and deserialization. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since you have custom serialization via `ISerializable`, we would need to see both the custom `GetObjectData` method and the custom deserialization constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This invariably means you have made an error in your custom `ISerializable` implementation; the following works fine:

```
protected Device(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    Name = info.GetString("Name");
    //...
    AssociatedMibEntity = (MibEntity)info.GetValue(
        "AssociatedMibEntity", typeof(MibEntity)); 
}
void ISerializable.GetObjectData(
    SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("Name", Name);
    //...
    info.AddValue("AssociatedMibEntity", AssociatedMibEntity);
}
```

with validation:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, new Device {
        AssociatedMibEntity = new MibEntity { Name = "Foo"}});
    ms.Position = 0;
    var clone = (Device)bf.Deserialize(ms);
    Console.WriteLine(clone.AssociatedMibEntity.Name); // Foo
}
```

However, unless there is a good reason to implement `ISerializable`, you might be better served by simply *removing* your `ISerializable` implementation completely - noting that this will be a breaking change (any existing data won't deserialize correctly if you do this).

```
[Serializable]
public class Device : IDisposable // <=== no ISerializable; also removed
                                  // GetObjectData and custom .ctor
```

Also: my usual rant: `BinaryFormatter` might not be your best bet if you are storing this data anywhere. It is... *brittle*. There are a range of far more reliable serializers.